# How do I create the template file for the form to add a new node?

Tags: theming, forms

I need to create the template file for the form used to add a new node, in order to change its layout for other users.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far, you stated facts, without asking any explicit question. (The title doesn't count as explicit question.) What exactly don't you understand in the task you described, the name to give to the template name or anything else? What did you try, and what did you get as result?

Comment: Are you using a admin-theme, or do you want this to work in your custom theme? Which version of drupal are you using?

Comment: Did you achieve this and how? in D8?